# Entering to my app hosted on firebase hosting redirects to google login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Was tweaking with Server Side Rendering and google cloud functions. Deployed everything on hosting and something really strange happens. When I enter my page, https://accounts.google.com page appears...

[image]

with some really long link:

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?
 service=ah&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fappengine.google.com
  %2F_ah%2Fconflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-treebase-
   b21-d5.cloudfunctions.net%2Fssrapp%2F&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=
    ServiceLogin&hl=en-GB
```

What may cause this? How to fix it? Thanks!

### `index.js` file responsible for SSR:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import express from 'express';
import App from './app/containers/App';
import functions from 'firebase-functions';

const app = express();

app.get('**', (req, res) => {
  const html = renderToString(<App />);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(`
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="app">${html}</div>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.30e39d69fe1ce70d8983.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});

export const ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

### `firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrapp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a complete and minimal example of project code that does this when you deploy it?  There needs to be a way to reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ive posted some files. Is it enough? Anyways, Im still struggling with enabling SSR with firebase and im failing miserably...

Comment: @DougStevenson Seems like I found what caused this. I've removed `index.html` file from the `public` folder. If I revert it, it shows the main page properly, but the same thing happens when I want to enter my app directly from nested components (nested routes, e.g. `/user/12`).

Comment: @DougStevenson I dont have any clue why does it happen... especially that in David East github repo he doesnt have any index.html file in the public directory. Just inside the functions. I did the same and that weird behaviour happened...

Answer (score 15):

If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for hosting, you must use us-central1

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client-callable_functions

Comment: awesome thank you for that! I'm a little bit disappointed that this important info cant be found in the docs

Comment: This is nuts, why this information not clearly communicated and the technical reason behind this is not explained.

Answer (score 1):

@Utwo is right. And if you still don't want to use us-central1 for your functions or don't want to mess around with firebase.json "rewrites" thing then you can enable CORS in firebase functions. That way, browsers would allow these functions to be called from other domains also.

```
exports.getData = functions.region("asia-east2").https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 // browsers like chrome need these headers to be present in response
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // you can also whitelist specific domain like "http://127.0.0.1:4000"
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

  // your code starts here

  //send response
  res.status(200).send();
});
```

This function will be deployed on https://asia-east2-your-project.cloudfunctions.net but you can call this function from your app/website which is hosted on other domain

Answer (score 0):

For ***Future*** reference and for those who aren't/don't wanna use `us-central1`.
Firebase allows only 3 regions for Cloud Functions.

[image]

So, for example if you're using **europe-west6** for other services, you can use **europe-west1** for your cloud functions.