# Firebase: How do you add a vanity URL to a cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Was briefly mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850375/use-custom-domain-for-google-cloud-function), but right now I'm at the point where I've connected my GCP project to Firebase, set up a custom domain under Firebase hosting, but on the functions page of the Firebase dashboard, there doesn't seem to be a way to set the vanity URL on a cloud function.

My firebase.json (at the root of my project) looks like :

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "rewrites": [
            { "source": "/helloWorld", "function": "helloWorld" },
            { "source": "/progress", "function": "progress" }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To associate a vanity domain with your Cloud Functions, you need to associate them with Firebase Hosting. See the [documentation on connecting the two](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

Say you have a Cloud Function `https://us-central1-<your-project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/bigben`.

After making this connection the function will also be available on `https://<your-project-id>.firebaseapp.com/bigben`.

If you also [connect a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) with Firebase Hosting, the function will also be available on `https://<your-custom-domain>.com/bigben`.

Comment: When I visit the url where my cloud function should be, I get a web page that says "404
Page Not Found
The specified file was not found on this website. Please check the URL for mistakes and try again.

Why am I seeing this?
This page was generated by the Firebase Command-Line Interface. To modify it, edit the 404.html file in your project's configured public directory."

Comment: Please edit your question to include the redirects from your `firebase.json` and to show how you've set up your custom domain.

Comment: Edited. Initially, my firebase.json was an empty object. Not sure how to redeploy the Firebase Hosting. I redeployed the cloud function on GCP by pressing edit and then saving (doesn't update when I push to git?), but the function deploy doesn't reflect in the Firebase console.

Comment: The custom domain only works for Cloud Functions deployed through Firebase's CLI (i.e. with `firebase deploy`). There is no other way for Firebase to know what functions you have and how to rewrite the URLs to them.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you know if there is a way to use path variables when redirecting to a Firebase Function? i.e. `source: ":path*", function: ":path"`. The docs show using a wildcard to redirect all paths to a single function, and they show using path variables when redirecting to other paths, but, in my testing, it seems like you cannot simply redirect `example.com/:functionName` to the proper function. Instead, you either need to individually create redirects for each function (not practical) or eliminate individual functions and create a single express app function.

Comment: Does not work at all for me with custom domain or `projectid.firebaseapp.com`

Comment: It is important to say that it only works for GET requests, as the "redirect" configuration is a real 301 redirection, and not a Google internal mapping...