# How to configure custom domain for Google Cloud Functions for rendering HTML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-functions, custom-domain

So I have deployed a Google Cloud Function to some place like this:

```
https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function
```

I can successfully render a dynamic webpage like this:

```
https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function?slug=foo
```

Now, I would like to put this behind a regular URL so it works like this:

```
https://my-domain.com/some-directory/foo
```

I would like for it to be **https** instead of http. And notice that I added `some-directory` above the `foo` slug, so there is a little bit of rewriting logic there.

So basically go from here to here:

```
https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/my-function?slug=foo
https://my-domain.com/some-directory/foo
```

The question is how to do this. Wondering if you could walk me through how to do it which I think would also help future googlers.

When I search "custom domain for google cloud function" I get [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/dev-portal-setup-custom-domain) which is for "endpoints" or "openapi" or I don't know, but it doesn't quite seem related. However, I went ahead anyways and changed my DNS nameservers to match what they said:

```
A     198.51.100.0
A     198.51.100.2
A     198.51.100.4
A     198.51.100.6
AAAA  2001:db8:ffff:32::15
AAAA  2001:db8:ffff:34::15
AAAA  2001:db8:ffff:36::15
AAAA  2001:db8:ffff:38::15
```

But I am lost as to what to do next. The documentation for Google Cloud is nothing compared to AWS which is unfortunate.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850375/use-custom-domain-for-google-cloud-function) is as close to what I've found so far, but it's still not even close to getting it working. Maybe [this](https://medium.com/wellzesta/hot-url-mapping-using-cloud-functions-49dad256d663) is closer to what I want.

Comment: This is a suggestion but not your answer. Google Cloud Run works perfectly for your use case plus is serverless containers. Custom domains are a built-in feature.

Comment: I have found this https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#hosting_on_the_same_domain  yet to implement / confirm

Answer (score 1):

Actually, is possible using Endpoints for cloud functions:

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions

After you have running your API or function in Cloud Run you just need to do a mapping with your custom domain (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains) and redeploy the OpenApi specification with the new host.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Google Cloud Functions deployed in a GCP project.

Currently, the only way to map a custom domain to your HTTP/S triggered functions is by using [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) and [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).

After creating the custom domain, you can configure the domain to [handle HTTPS/S triggered functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config).