# Google Cloud Functions Custom URL Redirect With BODY

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am using Google Cloud Functions with a custom domain to fire the functions.
I then realized something so bad during execution. With the normal URL (`https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/function`), my request maintains its headers and body and I can get the data sent to my function.

However, after redirection using firebase, all the requests are `GET` requests with `content-type` as text/plain and no data in that; completely empty.

**Is there a way that I could get this data in my cloud functions while still using a custom URL for my function?**

While looking for this, I came across this question >> [Use a custom domain for Google Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850375/use-custom-domain-for-google-cloud-function/58591136#58591136) << that I answered on how I have added my custom URL. 
This is exactly how I am using it.

Here is my debugging code for the function

```py
def function(request)

    content_type = request.headers['content-type']
    data = "not processed"

    if 'application/json' in content_type:
        data = str( request.get_json(force=True) )
    elif 'text/plain' in content_type:
        data = request.data.decode()
    else:
        return redirect('https://tradingview.to')

    print(data)
    return data
```