# Direct Firebase Hosting to Cloud Functions deployed in other regions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I updated the Firebase hosting rule following this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_requests_to_function) so I can have the cloud function end point using my own domain name. However it seems this only applies to the cloud function deployed in the default region in `us-central1`.

```js
"hosting": {
 "rewrites": [ {
   "source": "/endpoint",
   "function": "app"
 } ]
}
```

But whenever my functions are deployed like the following, the aforementioned the custom domain no longer works because it would still forward the requests to `us-central1` rather than `asia-east2` resulting in a 403 error.

```js
functions.region('asia-east2').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Does anyone know how this issue could be fixed? Many thanks!

Comment: It seems like functions for Firebase Hosting are intended to serve dynamic content for Firebase CDN which sources from `us-central1`. If what you require is a custom domain connecting to the function and do not tightly relied on Firebase CDN, I think you can give Cloudflare a try, setting CNAME on Cloudflare linking to the domain of your funciton in another region. Though not testing yet myself, I'm also finding a solution to this.

Comment: Ok, I find out that CNAME won't work. No need to try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61969054/8579025

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT Aug 2022: Now, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct-requests-to-function), regions can now specify non-default regions.

---

The behavior you're observing is expected, and documented.  From the Firebase Hosting [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions):

> Important: Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.