# What are the advantages of pairing Cloud Functions with Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Firebase docs has a page on how to [pair functions with hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions). In my use case, all my functions generate dynamic content so I will no be making use of cacheing on the CDN. I was wondering if there are any other reason why it may be advisable to pair functions with hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason to do this would be to get a custom host/domain name for your function endpoint.  Many don't care for the generated name that you get for free.

See: [Use custom domain for Google Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850375/use-custom-domain-for-google-cloud-function)