# How to deploy a Firebase app with firestore and express app to be globally accessible?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

We have successfully built a Firebase application with Firestore, functions, hosting, auth. Now we are working on an Atlassian confluence integration and a global rollout. The confluence plugin rest endpoints are served by an express app.

What is the proper way to achieve a unique url in all countries around the globe, e.g. `https://myapp.com/confluence/api` with no or at least acceptable latency to serve health checks as well? Is a hosting rewrite to function serving the express app enough? Do we need to manage any replication to regions around the globe by ourselves?

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firebase hosting to [connect a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain):

> use a custom domain (like `example.com` or `app.example.com`) instead
> of a Firebase-generated domain for your Firebase-hosted site.
>
> Firebase Hosting provisions an SSL certificate for each of your
> domains and serves your content over a global CDN.
>
> Note the following about connecting custom domains:
>
> - Each custom domain can only be connected to one Hosting site.
> - Each custom domain is limited to having 20 subdomains per apex domain, due to SSL certificate minting limits.

When Firebase verifies domain ownership, an SSL certificate is being provisioned for your domain and it's being deployed across [Firebase global CDN (content delivery network)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting). This delivery network cashes your content on Firebase edge servers' SSDs to ensure quick content delivery and low latency globally.

Comment: Thanks. What about firestore and functions content?

Comment: @Benjamin for Cloud Functions URL, please refer to the [Use custom domain for Google Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850375/use-custom-domain-for-google-cloud-function) thread. Let me know if it helps

Comment: The Firebase Hosting in front of the app works fine. However, we wondered about the global latency. For example, if the function/app is located in the US, an asian client might be pointed to the right function by the Hosting, but is served from the us and might experience an according latency.