# How do I invoke firebase cloud functions within the client using HTTP if the functions URLS will change depending on environment?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, serverless, non-deterministic

For example, my firebase cloud functions URL will be different in my emulator instance, my development Firebase project (online), and my production Firebase project (online).

On the client side, I would hardcode the URL and change the URL for each invocation upon deployment to match the function HTTP URL for the particular environment I am in. This is unsustainable and tedious. For example, if I had 10 invocations I would have to go through and change the fetch URLS each time I changed environments. If I wanted to test them in a non-prod environment later I would have to change them back. Is there any solution to this, I am using one codebase.

Per [Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http), eventually, the functions will feature deterministic URLS which means I can programmatically do this in the future using the .env. files but until then I'm not sure how to do this.

[image: Google cloud docs declaration of deterministic functions]

**TLDR**
I am trying to make it so that regardless of the environment the client is in it will be able to use the same URL across them to execute the respective function. i.e a DEV client would execute a DEV cloud function that would communicate with DEV servers.

Comment: For your last edit. Once you receive an answer, do not modify the question. That can make an answer incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

1. Use an HTTP load balancer and assign a custom domain name.

[Set up a global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic) with Cloud Run, App Engine, or Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless)

2. Use Firebase Hosting. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45853814/8016720).
3. Migrate your functions to Cloud Run and use custom domains.

[Mapping custom domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850375/use-custom-domain-for-google-cloud-function)

My preference is the third option, as Cloud Run is the big brother to Cloud Functions with many features that I wish Cloud Function had.

Firebase Hosting is another good option that brings another set of features for web-based applications.

The first option is a good choice for hiding Functions behind a proxy that protects your functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have a question about option 3. 

Assuming I have two google cloud (firebase) projects. How would I go about mapping them? Would I essentially map BOTH cloud functions (one in dev project and one in prod project) to the same domain? (such as map both copies of a function to function.DOMAIN.com)


To clarify: I am trying to make it so that regardless of the environment the client is in it will be able to use the same URL across them to execute the respective function. i.e a DEV client would execute a DEV cloud function that would communicate with DEV servers.

Comment: @AsharRahman - Option 3 is Cloud Run. Each Cloud Run app gets its own custom domain name. I use subdomains (app1.example.com, app2.example.com, etc). Once you select an option, I recommend posting a new question.